# Applications using Indy9 and Indy10

Tags: indy10, indy-9

So, In Delphi 7, If I have an application working with Indy9 and another working with Indy10 (my Delphi 7 on a VM), can I have a new VM with Delphi 7 and Indy10 for both apps? I'm thinking you can't have Indy9 and Indy10 installed on the same Delphi 7 build

thx all

Answer (score 0):

Indy 9 and Indy 10 are not compatible with each other.  You can have them both *installed* at the same time, as long as they are in separate folders, and you do not have them *loaded* at the same time.  For instance, one project can load and use Indy 9, and another project can load and use Indy 10.  It is generally a good idea to have your base IDE setup disable all installed packages, and then enable specific packages on a per-project basis as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response & info.
I will probably just have Indy 10 on my newer Delphi 7 VM and keep Indy 9 on my local build until I update my app